# T-SQL stored procedure with sorting and paging enabled not working properly

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using the following code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_get_all_groups] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pStartIndex smallint,
    @pPageSize tinyint,
    @pOrderBy varchar
AS
BEGIN

 SELECT 
       *
       FROM
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
        
        CASE WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId ASC' THEN UserGroups._id + ' ASC'
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId DESC' THEN UserGroups._id + ' DESC'
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode ASC' THEN UserGroups.GroupCode + ' ASC'
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode DESC' THEN UserGroups.GroupCode + ' DESC'
        END        
        ) AS Row, * FROM UserGroups)
       AS StudentsWithRowNumbers
         WHERE Row>= @pStartIndex AND Row <= @pStartIndex + @pPageSize
END
```

When I am executing the stored proc using the following command

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_get_all_groups]
        @pStartIndex = 0,
        @pPageSize = 15,
        @pOrderBy = N'GroupCode ASC'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I am getting these results which is not sorted.

```
Row _id GroupCode   Description Type    IsActive
1   1   CS2009  CS 2009 Batch   S   1
2   2   IT2009  IT 2009 Batch   S   1
3   3   ME2009  ME 2009 Batch   S   1
4   4   EC2009  EC 2009 Batch   S   1
5   5   EE2009  EE 2009 Batch   S   1
6   8   CS_F    CS Faculties    F   1
7   9   IT_F    IT Faculties    F   1
8   10  ME_F    ME Faculties    F   1
9   11  EC_F    EC Faculties    F   1
10  12  EE_F    EE Faculties    F   1
11  13  BSC_F   Basic Science Faculties F   1
12  14  Accounts    Accounts    A   1
13  15  Mgmt    Management  M   1
14  16  Lib Library B   1
15  17  TnP Training & Placement    T   1
```

Can you tell me what else is required?

---

I have tried this, but it is also giving plane unsorted result:

```
SELECT 
        GroupTable._id,
        GroupTable.GroupCode,
        GroupTable.Type,
        GroupTable.Description
       FROM
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
        
        CASE WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId ASC' THEN CONVERT(varchar(20), '_id ASC') 
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId DESC' THEN CONVERT(varchar(20), '_id DESC') 
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode ASC' THEN CONVERT(varchar(20), @pOrderBy) 
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode DESC' THEN CONVERT(varchar(20), @pOrderBy) 
        END        
        ) AS Row, * FROM UserGroups)
       AS GroupTable
         WHERE Row>= @pStartIndex AND Row <= @pStartIndex + @pPageSize
       
       Select COUNT(*) as TotalRows from UserGroups where IsActive= 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace your procedure with this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_get_all_groups] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pStartIndex smallint,
    @pPageSize tinyint,
    @pOrderBy varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN

 SELECT *
 FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId ASC' THEN UserGroups._id END ASC,  
      CASE WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId DESC' THEN UserGroups._id END DESC,             
      CASE WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode ASC' THEN UserGroups.GroupCode END ASC,
      CASE WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode DESC' THEN UserGroups.GroupCode END DESC) AS Row, 
      * FROM UserGroups) AS StudentsWithRowNumbers
  WHERE Row>= @pStartIndex AND Row <= @pStartIndex + @pPageSize
  ORDER BY Row      
END
```

You can't dynamically assign asc and desc to a non-dynamic expression.

Comment: It should work, is it a syntax error or is it not ordering correctly ?

Comment: Now after u have edited it, It has now accepted , but rows are not getting sorted :(

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be the misconception that the expression

```
ORDER BY UserGroups._id + ' DESC'
```

will cause SQL Server to apply a descending order. What it really does is simply append the string literal " DESC" to the column value and *then* sort the result in ascending order.

You need to dynamically create the whole SELECT statement in the procedure, applying the ORDER BY twice as sketched in marc_s' answer, and execute the statement using sp_executesql. sp_executesql also allows you to pass the @ parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing

```
@pOrderBy varchar(20) because of this your @pOrderBy has only one char 'G'
```

also check this [link](http://oops-solution.blogspot.com/2011/11/pagination-or-paging-in-sqlserver.html) may help you

Answer (score 1):

You're not ordering your `SELECT` statement .... neither the inner `SELECT` from `UserGroups` has an `ORDER BY`, nor does the outer `SELECT` .... you need to provide the `ORDER BY` on the `SELECT`, too! (not just in your `ROW_NUMBER()` function's `OVER()` clause)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
   (SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId ASC' THEN UserGroups._id + ' ASC'
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId DESC' THEN UserGroups._id + ' DESC'
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode ASC' THEN UserGroups.GroupCode + ' ASC'
             WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode DESC' THEN UserGroups.GroupCode + ' DESC'
        END) AS Row, * 
    FROM UserGroups) AS StudentsWithRowNumbers
WHERE 
     Row >= @pStartIndex AND Row <= @pStartIndex + @pPageSize
ORDER BY
    CASE 
       WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId ASC' THEN UserGroups._id + ' ASC'
       WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupId DESC' THEN UserGroups._id + ' DESC'
       WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode ASC' THEN UserGroups.GroupCode + ' ASC'
       WHEN @pOrderBy='GroupCode DESC' THEN UserGroups.GroupCode + ' DESC'
    END
```

The `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER()` clause is **only** used to compute the `Row` values - it does **not** order the resulting data set.

Comment: the ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified. when adding the following, i was not expecting such type of answer from you @marc_s please check before post

Comment: @RashmiKantShrivastwa: I would never do this with a correlated subquery - so I never use those myself. I would use a CTE myself (which does allow an `ORDER BY`) inside. Updated my answer...

Comment: still its not giving the result as expected

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help (if both _id and GroupCode are the same type):

```
DECLARE @pOrderBy VARCHAR(100),
        @pStartIndex smallint,
        @pPageSize tinyint
SET @pOrderBy='GroupId DESC'
SET @pStartIndex=0
SET @pPageSize=15
SELECT 
    GroupTable._id,
    GroupTable.GroupCode,
    GroupTable.Type,
    GroupTable.Description
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
    CASE @pOrderBy
        WHEN 'GroupId ASC'
        THEN UserGroups._id
        WHEN 'GroupCode ASC'
        THEN UserGroups.GroupCode
    END ASC,
    CASE @pOrderBy
        WHEN 'GroupId DESC'
        THEN UserGroups._id
        WHEN 'GroupCode DESC'
        THEN UserGroups.GroupCode
    END DESC    
    ) AS Row, * FROM UserGroups)
AS GroupTable
WHERE 
    Row>= @pStartIndex 
    AND Row <= @pStartIndex + @pPageSize
```