# Set number of pages in gridview with custom source

Tags: .net, gridview, paging, sqldatasource

Here is the scenario: I have gridView with sorting on TemplateField headers - SortExpression is set and gridView_Sorting function implemented.

I store sorting values and directions in ViewState.

I also don't retrieve all the records with SQL, but rather just "PageSize" records, pretty much similar that is described here:
[T-SQL stored procedure with sorting and paging enabled not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937145/t-sql-stored-procedure-with-sorting-and-paging-enabled-not-working-properly)

I use List as data source.

Now, my problem is, that because I retrieve only "PageSize" of records my paging is not displayed.
gridView.PageCount can not be set, since it is read only.
If I use objectDataSource as a source then my sorting doesn't work as it should.
Now it works just fine - for the first page ... since paging is not displayed.

So, how can I set number of pages for my GridView?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL server 2008.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.