# Mvc Telerik grid With large database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, telerik-grid

I  am  using  telerik mvc grid in my mvc project  , my  table  have  around 1 Million records. My  grid  taking  too  much  time  to  load.

This  is  my  Query
//

```
  var bib = (from a in db.Bibs
                   join inf in db.InfoTypes
                   on a.InfoTypeId equals inf.Id
                   where a.Status == "A"

                   select new BibViewModel
                   {
                       Id = a.Id,
                       Type = inf.Type,
                       InfoType = inf.Description,
                       Title = (from asd in db.BibContents where asd.BibId == a.Id && asd.TagNo == "245" && asd.Sfld == "a" select asd.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                       Author = (from asd in db.BibContents where asd.BibId == a.Id && asd.TagNo == "100" && asd.Sfld == "a" select asd.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                       CatalogueDate = a.CatalogDate,
                       Contents = "",
                       CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn,
                       ItemRelation = db.Items.Any(item => item.BibId == a.Id),
                       IssueRelation = db.Issues.Any(item => item.BibId == a.Id),

                   });


        return View(new GridModel(bib.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).Tolist()));
```

Comment: You have a crazy lot of joins and nested searches. One thing i notice is that you store Status as a string datatype which is much more demanding than using an int instead. If you remove the where clause 'where a.Status == "A"' and instead take 10000 rows with 'take 10000' does it execute any faster? Just a suggestion which might lead you to a solution.

Comment: actually  my  query  is   not taking  much time..my  return  query  taking  lot  of  time  to  return  bcoj  i  am  using  Tolist..  If  i  remove  tolist  then  i  have  others  error  "like  Time  Out  Server  Error"

Answer (score 0):

`ToList()` actually invokes the query, so if calling `ToList()` is taking too long, that means the issue is with the query.

In LINQ, you can use paging like in [the following post](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/paging-through-lists-with-linq); the idea is to use Skip and Take to skip X records, and only take Y records, as in:

```
var results = (from .. select ..).Skip(X).Take(Y)
```

With 1M records, I would highly suggest replacing it with a stored procedure, which will be much, much faster for what you are trying to do.  Consider a custom pagination approach, which works very well for me with large result sets:

- http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/dynamic-paging-in-sql-server-stored-procedures/
- http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Paging-Stored-Procedures.aspx
- http://www.sqlpointers.com/2009/10/custom-sorting-and-paging-in-sql-server.html
- [T-SQL stored procedure with sorting and paging enabled not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937145/t-sql-stored-procedure-with-sorting-and-paging-enabled-not-working-properly)

If you can't use stored procedures, reading this will help understand what needs to be accomplished with pagination.  With LINQ, you'll want to examine the SQL being generated to see where you also can fine-tune the query, either using SQL profiler, or [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: acc.  to  client  we  cannot  use  sp  in  our  project

Comment: Wow, that's not good. You can, however, implement the same feature in LINQ like so: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/paging-through-lists-with-linq .  You will get much better performance if you only take the records you need at the time.  I edited my response above.